# react and conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am using the following code to conditionally render some HTML based on `hasLocations` variable.

Code works, but I wish to know if there is a better way to achieve the same result, for example, I am not sure having two `return` is a good practice.

```
const Finder = ({ locations, onLocationClick }) => {
  let hasLocations = locations.length > 0
  if (hasLocations) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {locations.map((location, index) =>
          <Location
            key={index}
            {...locations[index]}
            onLocationClick={() => onLocationClick(location)}
      />
    )}
      </ul>
    )
  } else {
    return (null)
  }
}
```

Comment: Having multiple returns in a function is not a bad practice, at all.

Comment: I concur with @IvankaTodorova. Even if your logic somehow breaks or is flawed, only one return can ever actually execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you chould use [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html). For your example, this would look like this.

```
const Finder = ({ locations, onLocationClick }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {locations.length > 0 &&
            locations.map((location, index) =>
                <Location
                    key={index}
                    {...locations[index]}
                    onLocationClick={() => onLocationClick(location)}
                />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

EDIT: My solution would be the following.
I would avoid adding any logic in it(AKA presentational component). So it would become

```
    const Finder = ({ locations, onLocationClick }) => {
        return (
            <ul>
                locations.map((location, index) =>
                <Location
                    key={index}
                    {...locations[index]}
                    onLocationClick={() => onLocationClick(location)}
                />
                )
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

And when you need to use it you can do something like this:

```
    return (
        <div>
            {locations.length > 0 && Finder}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: but in this case react will always render the <ul> tag instead I need not to render the entire <ul> if not items are in locations.

Comment: @Radex You could move the condition to the ul, and change it to || null, or use conditional rendering before using the "Finder" const to avoid this. As to if having multiple return statements is bad practise I would say no. I usually rely on it for my components.

Comment: Could you please provide me a simple example in your answer, so I can compare both solutions thanks!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html
You have everything here, you can use the inline IF, but here it would be overkill. As @ivanka said, having two return in the same renderer is no problem. I even find it easier to understand in this kind of case.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using multiple returns in a function, but when you do it's good practice to put a "default" return as the last statement in the function to make it more apparent that the function always returns something.
In your case that means you could move your `return (null)` (no need to wrap `null` in brackets, btw) statement out of the `else` clause and just put it as the last statement of the function.

It's also possible to use a single return statement with ternary in your `return`, like this:

```
return locations.length > 0 ? (
  <ul>
    {locations.map((location, index) =>
      <Location
        key={index}
        {...locations[index]}
        onLocationClick={() => onLocationClick(location)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
) : null
```